Clang rejects inexplicit enum value in constexpr function (gcc works)
In the following example Clang fails only in the constexpr version of the function:
enum foo { bar };

auto baz() { return static_cast<foo>(-1); }
constexpr auto barf() { return static_cast<foo>(-1); }

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/b13M4v4xx
gcc accepts both versions.
Is this is bug in clang? If not, then why does it only fail in constexpr context?
UPDATE
If I add storage class (eg, enum foo : char { bar };), that makes clang happy... but doesn't answer my question. :)
UPDATE
If clang is correct, as several people have suggested, then why does the following fail:
enum foo { bar };

constexpr struct { int qux :1; } quux{-1};

auto baz() { return static_cast<foo>(quux.qux); }
constexpr auto barf() { return static_cast<foo>(quux.qux); }

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/61dWobbvo
According to c++17 foo should have a storage of 1-bit bit-field, which is what quux.qux is. Yet, this still fails on clang.

I don't understand what storage class means in your update - can you elaborate?

Is this is bug in clang? No. If not, then why does it only fail in constexpr context?  Probably IF/NDR.  Or could be a bug in GCC.  But IANALL.

@Super-intelligentShade you might find it interesting to experiment with bool and unsigned char which are closer to what the compiler will do

@Eljay constexpr is not allowed to compile in the context of UB, in the non-constexpr case everything will compile (and probably seem to run correctly too)

"constexpr is not allowed to compile in the context of UB" First, we need to establish, whether it actually is UB or a bug in clang. See my updated question.

foo is an enumeration type that is said to be without a fixed underlying type, because it isn't a scoped enumeration and doesn't explicitly specify an underlying type.
In contrast to all other enumeration types, enumerations without fixed underlying type do not share their value range with that of their underlying type.
Instead [dcl.enum]/8 specifies that their range is limited to effectively the minimal range necessary to represent all its enumerators and all of their bitwise-or combinations (at least as long as all enumerators have non-negative value).
In particular, your enumeration foo has only one enumerator with value 0. And so the range according to the above heuristic is just the value 0. The exact wording in C++17 gives the same result. In C++20 the wording was changed and it is now less clear, but that is likely just an unintended wording defect, see CWG 2932.
So, -1 is not a valid value for foo. [expr.static.cast]/10 states that behavior is undefined when attempting to cast an integral type expression to an enumeration without fixed underlying type if its value is outside the enumerations range. When undefined behavior would happen during evaluation of an expression, then that expression can't be a constant expression and therefore something like
constexpr auto r = barf();

would be ill-formed.
Now, you do not actually call barf in a context that requires a constant expression in your question. In that case, before C++23 the function definition itself was IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required) because it could never be called in a constant expression, meaning that a compiler could diagnose that constexpr on it would never actually allow it to be used in a constant expression and could fail to compile it.
With C++23 this was changed and a function declared with constexpr is now not IFNDR just because it can't be called in a constant expression. Only actually calling it where a constant expression is required is now ill-formed.
In your second example nothing changes. The value of quux.qux is still -1 and its type still int, causing the same rules to apply as above.

From my testing, at the moment Clang seems to be the only compiler that actually diagnoses use of invalid values in enumeration types during constant evaluation. The other compilers are behaving non-conforming.
Note that, although the cast is undefined behavior, as far as I am aware, in default configurations, current compilers do not actually assume that the range of enumerations without fixed underlying type is limited in the way the standard specifies. So it is relatively safe to still use it at runtime. I am at least pretty sure about GCC and Clang, both of which have a special optimization flag -fstrict-enums, which is not enabled by any -O flag, to tell the compiler to actually make use of the limited range for optimization.

Thanks for the more formal references :)

GCC bug 95701? https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95701

Since C++17 an enum has defined storage as the smallest bitfield that can hold all of the enum values. So for foo that would be a bitfield of size 1.
Your -1 needs ALL the bits of the underlying type and casting it
is thus UB
So clang is right to reject it. This demo shows that :
enum foo { zero, one, two};

// these do compile
constexpr auto bar0() { return static_cast<foo>(1); }
constexpr auto bar1() { return static_cast<foo>(1); }
constexpr auto bar2() { return static_cast<foo>(2); }
constexpr auto bar3() { return static_cast<foo>(3); } // even though 3 is not a "valid" enum value it can be cast (to a bitfield with 2 bits)

// does not compile
constexpr auto bar4() { return static_cast<foo>(4); } // 4 doesn't fit into a 2 bit bitfield.

Also see : Lightning Talk: So You Thought C++ Was Weird? Meet Enums - Roth Michaels - CppCon 2021

@Super-intelligentShade Initialization is orthogonal here. This is the same as bool b = -1;.

@3CxEZiVlQ apparently it's not: https://godbolt.org/z/dP379j6KE

I have also tried https://godbolt.org/z/5Wcvzh1Yq and I found it to be like a Catch-22.

"our -1 needs ALL the bits of the underlying type and casting it is thus UB": The underlying representation of the value is completely irrelevant. It is only relevant whether the value itself is within range for the enumeration type. And a bit-field of size 1 could hold -1, assuming it is signed.

Also, the whole behavior importantly applies only to enumeration types without fixed underlying type. Otherwise there will be appropriate conversions in the cast.

Since C++17? What did C++17 change, I thought it was always like this?

@HolyBlackCat AFIAK It was formalized... and I understood that before C++17 it was implementation defined.
